# "developer/test" mode for SQL Databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, testing

I am new to a relatively large project using a Microsoft SQL server database with C# and the Entity Framework.

The current development process is like this:

- Code some feature/intend to fix a bug
- Start the application
- Make some changes via GUI to the database testing the coded functionality/testing if the bug was fixed
- In case of failure -> run SQL scripts to delete the complete database changes and repeat the whole procedure

I am wondering if there is any "test/developer"-mode for SQL databases that could automatically revert the applied changes. Basically, while the program is running, everything should be inserted/updated/deleted to the actual database, but afterwards all changes should automatically be reverted. Is my thought completely unreasonable? Is our procedure with the SQL scripts more or less state of the art for database development?

Thanks in advance!

*Edit* : We are using a developer database and the code first approach of Entity. It is still very annoying to me to run SQL scripts every time to keep my developer database "clean/usable/free from corrupt data". Also sometimes you code functionality that is supposed to work only once in production and coding that feature, requires you to test it a couple of times which means you need to reset the database once/times tested.

Comment: To make sure I understand what is being asked...you run test against live, and want to revert anything that occurs in these test after they are completed?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Entity Framework, but 'reverting changes on failure' is a job you can handle at a SQL Server level. It's transactional, so you can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-transaction-transact-sql transaction rollback on failure.

Comment: your "test/developer" mode should be a test/developer database which should be (at minimal) a structural mirror of whatever the live database has, along with any changes you're currently working on.  Whenever these changes are ready to roll live, make the changes to the live database and push the (now known working) changes for the db and the code live.  You should ideally never be testing anything in a production environment.

Comment: @Leonidas199x No, we run tests against a developer database, but still would like to revert everything afterwards.

Comment: @JonathonOgden Since we are using SQL scripts to delete the data. This is basically what we are doing already more or less, no?

Comment: @user2366842 We are not testing in production. It is still annoying to revert changes in the development database.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No you can not do that in SQL Server unless you backup everytime you want to make some changes to database and restore it when something went wrong!

Long answer:
Developing and Testing on a production database is a bad idea. Developers must have their own database in order to develop and test their code against database. Also it's better to abstract database in your code in order to make your code unit-testable without needing a real database.

If you don't want to go with abstracting your database, You still need to work with a test database.

Using EntityFramework + SQL Server so you can use [Code First approach](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx) to [map database to code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx).

Also you can use [Entity Framework Migrations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-based-migration-in-code-first.aspx) to track changes in Data Definition Level.

And if you need your fresh database have some inital data, you can use [seed method in database initializer](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/seed-database-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have mentioned a couple more details: We are not testing on a production database, but it is still annoying to revert changes to a development database. We already use the code first approach.